# Sequelize: Why Is This $or Not Working?

Tags: sequelize.js

This works:

```
        var args = {fromID: 1, toID: 2};
        var altArgs = {};
        altArgs.fromID = args.toID;
        altArgs.toID = args.fromID;
        var ret = connectors.IM.findAll({ $or: [args, altArgs] }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
```

But this doesn't, even though in terms of $or syntax, it looks exactly the same to me:

```
        const {fromID, toID} = args;
        var fromArgs = {};
        var toArgs = {};
        fromArgs.userID = fromID;
        toArgs.userID = toID;

        var ret = connectors.myUserData.findAll({ $or: [fromArgs, toArgs] }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
```

The myUserData does contain a userID field, and the values I am looking for are to be found in the table.  What is preventing the second code block from working?

Comment: You missed `where` prop: `.findAll({where: { $or: [fromArgs, toArgs]}})`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! Please re-post as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer. `var ret = connectors. myUserData.findAll({where: { $or: [fromArgs, toArgs]}}).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));`

Answer (score 0):

There's missed where prop: `.findAll({where: { $or: [fromArgs, toArgs]}})`